# Print value of a NSString which is set inside a autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to `NSLog` value of a `NSString` which is references inside a `@autoreleasepool`, but XCode complains of **Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'NSString *__autoreleasing **'**

```
anotherFunction {

NSString *myString = nil;
 compute =  [self checkForError:data myString:&myString];
}


- (NSDictionary *)checkForError:(NSData *)data myString:(NSString **)myString {

    @autoreleasepool { 
            *myString = nil;
            @try {
                NSMutableString *myString1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                // do something on myString1
                  *myString = myString1;
  ------>              NSLog(@"mutableString is:%s", myString );  // Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'NSString *__autoreleasing **'
            }

    }

    return myDictionary;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but what is the question? `%s` specifies type `char*` but `myString` has type `NSString**`.

Answer (score 1):

(I totally misread the question).

So, yeah-- use '%@' for object types.   Pass *myString to NSLog() to convert an NSString ** to an NSString *.

Note that you should probably be using `NSError` to encapsulate the errors and you should check to see if your pass by reference parameter is NULL before assigning to it.

See:

https://nshipster.com/nserror/

Comment: @Willeke At least not in a reasonable way.